# Automatically detecting file extensions

Tags: python

As you can see this is very very clunky. How would I go about automatically detecting file extension?

```
txt_files = glob('*txt')
png_files = glob('*.png')
jpg_files = glob('*.jpg')
zip_files = glob('*.zip')
gif_files = glob('*.gif')
iso_files = glob('*iso')
epub_files = glob('*epub')
ico_files = glob('*.ico')

#Unimportant bit to question

for n in txt_files:
    move_files(n, 'txt')
for n in png_files:
    move_files(n, 'png')
for n in jpg_files:
    move_files(n, 'jpg')
for n in zip_files:
    move_files(n, 'zip')
for n in gif_files:
    move_files(n, 'gif')
for n in iso_files:
    move_files(n, 'iso')
for n in epub_files:
    move_files(n, 'epub')
for n in ico_files:
    move_files(n, 'ico')
```

Comment: Is there a reason some of your extensions have the `.` and some don't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To "automatically detect new extensions", just go through all the files and look at their extensions:

```
for f in os.listdir():
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    ext = ext.lstrip('.')
    if ext:
        os.mkdirs(ext)
        move_file(filename, ext)
```

Note that this won't work if some of your "extensions" aren't actually extensions. I notice that your existing code searches for things like `*txt` and `*iso`, which will of course match stuff like `this_is_not_txt` and `spam.aniso` and so forth. If that's a required feature rather than a bug, then you're going to have to come up with some rule for what you mean by "extension" before you can implement it in code…

Also notice that files without an extension at all will be left where they are (because of that `if ext:`), and files with an empty extension (just `.`) will be as well (because the `if` check happens after the `lstrip`). You can of course change either of those if desired (although you'll need to come up with a subdirectory name that can't possibly be ambiguous with any possible actual extension…).

Finally, this won't handle "double extensions"—for example, `.tar.gz` files will go into the same directory as `.gz`. Again, this is easy to change if desired.

Comment: Probably worth noting that files without a "." extension will be ignored.

Comment: @martineau: OK, I'm not sure it's necessary, but I've added it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ext in "txt png jpg zip gif iso epub ico".split():
    for file in glob("*.%s"%ext): #if there are no files of this type it just skips it
        move_files(file,ext)
```

maybe?  its not very clear what your question is

In some sense this is "auto detected" since if there are no files that fit the pattern it will skip the `move_files` step

Comment: How does this "automatically detect new extensions"? It's just a more compact way of writing the logic he already has (except that you included the `*` only on `txt`).

Comment: yeah I dont know what he means by that statement ...  I was just addressing his statement "As you can see this is very very clunk." (I think he meant clunky... but he doesnt specify how its clunky)

Comment: You're right, it's a bit ambiguous. I suppose he could mean that he wants to clean up this code, and then also write some extra code at the end to detect leftover extensions after the moves (e.g., `unexpected_extensions = {os.path.splitext(f)[1] for f in os.listdir() if os.path.isfile(f)}`)?

Comment: (anyway I gave you +1 ... because I expect that is more what he is looking for ... maybe ...)